# VB.NET - Date Time Picker saves current date by default, even if no date is chosen

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

I have a date picker named 'paidDateDp' in my form. My configuration is as below

Property Setting:
    Format="Custom"

```
Private Sub paidDateDp_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles paidDateDp.ValueChanged
        paidDateDp.CustomFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
    End Sub
```

While executing, I see the paidDateDp value is blank. Even if I dint choose any value, when I attempt to save the details of the form to MSAccess using my Oledbadapter query, by default, the current date is getting saved against the paidDate column of my access table.

How to save empty date to my access table from my datetime picker, provided no date is selected?

Someone please suggest me.

Comment: Does your `paidDate` column have a default value defined?

Comment: The `Value` property of a `DateTimePicker` is type `DateTime`.  That is a value type, so the property can't possibly not have a value.  The fact that you have set the `CustomFormat` to not display anything in the control doesn't change that.  You'd have to test some condition when it comes time to save and use `DBNull.Value` explicitly if the user hasn't set the `Value` of the control.

Comment: @SamAxe .No in my access table, I dont have any default value for paidDate column.  I dont have any default value in its vb.net control properties as well.

Comment: You could define a boolean variable to use as a flag to see if the control was clicked on. Set it using the Picker's click event and in the ValueChanged event, if it has been clicked, assign the date to `paidDateDp.CustomFormat` and reset the flag. If the Picker hasn't been clicked, assign an obviously out of range date for example #01/01/2001#